# How do I register a paper URL into doai.io or oadoi.org?

Tags: open-access

[oaDOI.org](https://oadoi.org/) and [doai.io](http://doai.io/) are services that give open-access links based on DOI.

How can I register a paper into doai.io or oadoi.org?

Answer (score 7):

[doai.io](http://doai.io/) relies on [BASE (Bielefeld Academic Search Engine)](http://www.base-search.net/)'s data. So to  register a paper into [doai.io](http://doai.io/), one has to put it in an open-access repository that is harvested by BASE. There are more than 5700+ indexed repositories, the [complete list can be found here](https://www.base-search.net/about/en/about_sources_date.php)

[oaDOI.org](https://oadoi.org/) relies on its own harvesting of open-access repositories, that are listed at https://api.oadoi.org/data/sources.csv